# Using Asp.net Core MVC Bootstrap 4 and I can't get the unobtrusive validation working quite right for server side added modelstate errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, unobtrusive-validation

Everything seems to work great with the validation annotations on the view model. However, I am having issues when, on the server-side (after a form post), I do some additional validations and add modelstate errors. Those errors actually render appropriately and come through in the response from the server, however, the errors that are associated with one of the properties/inputs on the form, those end up getting cleared out some how. Now, if I put the validation summary on the page, the message does show there, but the message related directly to the input doesn't show and the input isn't marked as invalid any longer. Any idea on what might be going on?

I'm using jQuery v2.1.4, jQuery Validation v1.14.0, jQuery Validation Unobtrusive v3.2.6, Bootstrap 4.4.1, and I am using version v2.2.0 of this plugin: https://github.com/brecons/jquery-validation-unobtrusive-bootstrap. I couldn't get any of the BS4 validation stuff working/looking right until I found that plugin that I just mentions. Now it works and looks great, but server-side added modelstate errors don't end up coming through to the client like I would like. And I think that they are coming form the server to the client ok in the response, but I think that there is possibly some script processing that is clearing those error messages. I figure someone has solved this issue by now.

The cshtml setup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="email" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" />
    _<span asp-validation-for="Email" class="invalid-feedback"></span>_
</div>
the server-side add model error statement:
this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(LoginViewModel.Email), "Your account has been disabled.");
```

The response as it came from the server to the client:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email Address</label>
    <input class="form-control input-validation-error" type="email" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." id="Email" name="Email" value="disabled@rew.com" />
    _<span class="invalid-feedback field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true">Your account has been disabled.</span>_
</div>
```

This is from an inspection of the page after the page shows in the browser. As you can see the validation message that came from the server is gone and the input is cleared of the error:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email Address</label>
    <input class="form-control input-validation-error is-valid" type="email" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." id="Email" name="Email" value="disabled@rew.com" style="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="Email-error">
    <div id="Email-error" class="is-invalid invalid-feedback" style="display: block;"></div>
    _<span class="invalid-feedback field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>_
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom css for this to work

> `.field-validation-error { color:red; font-size: smaller; }`
>
> `.input-validation-error{ border-color: #dc3545; }`

Because the validation-for in dotnet MVC use this class in the rendered html:

> `<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Customer.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true">The Name field is required.</span>`
>
> `<input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Name must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Customer_Name" maxlength="255" name="Customer.Name" type="text" value="">`

Credit to this blog:
https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-bootstrap-style-validation-in-aspnet-core/